# python Connecting To Multiple Sessions over QuickFix

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

So i have to connect to two(2) sessions (same host different ports) so i used two different initiator

```
    application = Application()

    settings = quickfix.SessionSettings(config_file)  # stream settings
    storefactory = quickfix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
    logfactory = quickfix.FileLogFactory(settings)
    initiator = quickfix.SocketInitiator(
        application, storefactory, settings, logfactory)

    initiator.start()

    application.run()

    initiator.stop()
```

and used two different config (.cfg) files for both sessions

```
# This is a client (initiator)
[DEFAULT]
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.4.4
 #settings which apply to all the Sessions.
ConnectionType=initiator
 # FIX messages have a sequence ID, which shouldn't be used for uniqueness as specification doesn't guarantee anything about them. If Y is provided every time logon message is sent, server will reset the sequence.
FileLogPath=./Logs/
 #Path where logs will be written
StartTime=00:00:00
 # Time when session starts and ends
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
 #Time in seconds before your session will expire, keep sending heartbeat requests if you don't want it to expire
ReconnectInterval=60
LogoutTimeout=5
LogonTimeout=30
 # Time in seconds before reconnecting
ResetOnLogout=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
SendRedundantResendRequests=Y
# RefreshOnLogon=Y
SocketNodelay=N
# PersistMessages=Y
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
# CheckLatency=Y



# session stream
[SESSION]
ResetOnLogon=Y
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=TESTING1
TargetCompID=TESTACC1
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=4000
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
DataDictionary=./spec/FIX44.xml
FileStorePath=./Sessions/

# session market
[SESSION]
ResetOnLogon=Y
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=TESTING2
TargetCompID=TESTACC2
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=5000
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
DataDictionary=./spec/FIX44.xml
FileStorePath=./Sessions/
```

But this doesn't work

I saw a post where they recommended using `ThreadedSocketInitiator` but i don't think its used on the python quickfix lib.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ThreadedSocketInitiator` has nothing to do with your problem. It just maintains one thread per FIX session whereas the default `SocketInitiator` utilizes the same thread for all FIX sessions. Is that your complete config file? Usually you need a `[SESSION]` line in front of each session definition. Sample file: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/configuration.html#Sample%20Settings%20File

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure how the Python port of QuickFIX does this, but usually you only need one Initiator and pass one config file with multiple sessions. See example file above.

Comment: Nice Thanks  Christoph John, i have refactored my code and added two [SESSION] to my config file, but now just one port is connecting the other isn't connecting

Comment: Could you please update the question with your complete config file?

Comment: @ChristophJohn i have updated the Config and the code